# MySQL - Count unique users each day considering all previous days

Tags: mysql

I would like to count how many new unique users the database gets each day for all days recorded.
There will not be any duplicate ids per day, but there will be duplicates over multiple days.

If my table looks like this :

```
ID | DATE
---------
1  | 2022-05-21

1  | 2022-05-22
2  | 2022-05-22

1  | 2022-05-23
2  | 2022-05-23

1  | 2022-05-24
2  | 2022-05-24
3  | 2022-05-24
```

I would like the results to look like this :

```
DATE       | NEW UNIQUE IDs
---------------------------
2022-05-21 | 1
2022-05-22 | 1
2022-05-23 | 0
2022-05-24 | 1
```

A query such as :

```
SELECT `date` , COUNT( DISTINCT id)
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY DATE( `date` )
```

Will return the count per day and will not take into account previous days.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit : Using MySQL 8

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL Version 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is new when the date is the least date for this user.

So you need in something like

```sql
SELECT date, COUNT(new_users.id)
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, MIN(date) date
            FROM test 
            GROUP BY id ) new_users USING (date)
GROUP BY date
```

`calendar` is either static or dynamically generated table with needed dates list. It can be even `SELECT DISTINCT date FROM test` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a subquery showing the earliest date where each id appears.

```
            SELECT MIN(`date`) `firstdate`, id
              FROM tbl
             GROUP BY id
```

Then do your count on that subquery. [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/snznCmEtxnUAxCo5s97VqD/0).

```
SELECT firstdate, COUNT(*)
  FROM (
            SELECT MIN(`date`) `firstdate`, id
              FROM tbl
             GROUP BY id
       ) m
 GROUP BY firstdate
```

That gives you what you want.

But it doesn't have rows for the dates where no new user ids first appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Only count (and sum) the rows where the left join fails:

```
SELECT 
    m1.`DATE` , 
    sum(CASE WHEN m2.id is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as C
FROM mytable m1
LEFT JOIN mytable m2 ON m2.`DATE`<m1.`DATE` AND m2.ID=m1.ID
GROUP BY m1.`DATE`
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d263d72ece965c82ad1f1eb509f56919)

Comment: May die on huge table...

Comment: Maybe I was a bit too focused on "considering all previous days" , but before _dying_ it will be slower... see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11e0c7a89a9f50526ba5a783562ef396)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9d0ffd1d73c4bfff964ad6e3a81c95f The more the rows amount the more the absolute execution time difference...

Comment: True, but we are both missing "There will not be any duplicate ids per day"  (so, `PRIMARY KEY x(ID,`DATE`)` should be added to the table definition.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f7fb43fcbff47a66b7d06ba8b3a3849

Comment: It takes time before MySQL is dying, incrementing the count to `50000` still produces results within a second,  and _only_ () six times slower  (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bb30b9813553f8f96caf8c13ba31399)

Comment: Yes, if "one used per day" then the table is not huge. And server won't have problems.

Comment: `SELECT `DATE`, count(*) from mytable GROUP By `DATE` ORDER By 2 DESC LIMIT 40;` shows dates with 60+ records.... (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=648dc3f2e256e4813b7efc9f8e1d72c0)